# Where does the output of `at` and `cron` jobs go?

Tags: cron, output, at

Where does standard output from `at` and `cron` tasks go, given there
is no screen to display to?

It's not appearing in the directory the jobs were started from, nor in
my home directory.

How could I actually figure this out given that I don't know how to
debug or trace a background job?

Comment: Output is usually sent via email.

Comment: I recommend using mutt, "a small but very powerful text-based mail client", to read the output. It is has been in the repositories for every distro I've used.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the cron man page:

> When executing commands, any output is mailed to the owner of  the
>   crontab  (or  to the user named in the MAILTO environment variable in
>   the crontab, if such exists).  The children copies of cron running
>   these processes have their name coerced to uppercase, as will be seen
>   in the syslog and ps output.

So you should check your/root's mail, or the syslog (eg. /var/log/syslog).

Comment: On my mac, after simply calling "cron" it displayed the path to the "email". In my case , it was /var/mail/<username>.

Answer (score 8):

For long-running processes it is sometimes useful to know what the
output is before you get the email, I use this instead:

1. Use `ps` to find the process ID of your running program (`PID`
   below);
2. use `lsof` to find the file the output is being written to:

   ```
   lsof -p PID
   ```

In the output, look for the `1u` and `2u` lines under the `FD` column header.

These lines will tell you what temporary files the process output is
going into before it is sent by mail. Typically, for `at`, the file is
located under `/var/spool/cron/atjobs/`. Finally, display that file
and you will find your process' (current) output.

Comment: the files under `1u` and `2u` are of type `UNIX`. I'm guessing these are UNIX sockets. How do I look into the files now?

Comment: What to do when `1u` and `2u` files appear as `(deleted)` (although the process itself is still running)?

Answer (score 2):

@kapad, @janaka:
This is now answered in [How can I access a deleted open file on Linux (output of a running crontab task)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61820/how-can-i-access-a-deleted-open-file-on-linux-output-of-a-running-crontab-task)

So in this case, you'd do a something along the lines of

"`tail /proc/[the-pid]/fd/1`"