# How can I access a deleted open file on Linux (output of a running crontab task)?

Tags: linux, data-recovery, open-files, deleted-files

I have an hourly hour-long crontab job running with some `mtr` (`traceroute`) output every 10 minutes (that is going to go for over an hour prior to it being emailed back to me), and I want to see the current progress thus far.

On Linux, I have used `lsof -n | fgrep cron` (`lsof` is similar to BSD's `fstat`), and it seems like I might have found the file, but it is annotated as having been deleted (a standard practice for temporary files is to be deleted right after opening):

```
COMMAND     PID       USER   FD      TYPE     DEVICE  SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME
...
cron      21742       root    5u      REG      202,0      7255      66310 /tmp/tmpfSuELzy (deleted)
```

And cannot be accesses by its prior name anymore:

```
# stat /tmp/tmpfSuELzy
stat: cannot stat `/tmp/tmpfSuELzy': No such file or directory
```

**How do I access such a deleted file that is still open?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The file can be access through the `/proc` filesystem: you already know the *PID* and the *FD* from the `lsof` output.

```
cat /proc/21742/fd/5
```

Comment: These are symbolic links to the file... does it still work when the file is deleted?

Comment: @BonsiScott: Every files in `/proc` is fake. For `/proc/*/fd/` files, When calling `stat` on them, they tell you it's a symbolic link, when you call `readlink` on them, they return whatever they want (in this case, an absolute path to the file that was opened), and when you call `open` and `read` on them, you get access to a somewhat real file with content.  The same holds true for many files in `/proc`. For example, most dynamically generated files have a file size of zero, yet they have contents.

Comment: Many tools also allow you to deliberately dereference symlinks - for example, I used `ls -l --dereference-command-line /proc/1234/fd/5` to check the size of an open but deleted file.