# How can I peek at the output of a running crontab task on OpenBSD?

Tags: cron, openbsd

I have an hourly hour-long crontab task running with some `mtr` (`traceroute`) output every 10 minutes (that is going to go for over an hour prior to it being emailed back to me), and I want to see the current progress thus far.

On Linux, it can be done by [accessing the open fd of the temporary file to which the results of the script are saved](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61820/how-can-i-access-a-deleted-open-file-on-linux-output-of-a-running-crontab-task/61821#61821).

How can I do this on OpenBSD?

I've tried doing `fstat | fgrep -e USER -e cron -e mtr`, but couldn't find any temporary files at all.

Comment: Whether the cron job runs for one hour and gives the output ?

Answer (score 2):

I’ve investigated the source as to how cron handles mailing the output from its jobs:

- `cron(8)` sets up stdout and stderr of the running job and pipes it directly into `mail(1)`, not leaving any temporary files.  Look in `do_command.c` around line 411 ([1](http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.sbin/cron/do_command.c?annotate=1.38)).
- `mail(1)` needs to fully ready its stdin, since it needs the headers.  It opens a temporary file (usually `/tmp/mail-R…`), but removes it right away, as not to leave traces.  Loøk in `collect.c` at line 83 ([2](http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/mail/collect.c?annotate=1.34)).

In any case, there seems to be deliberate effort *not* to leave an interceptible temporary file lying around.  If you need (or want) to intercept what’s going on in a long-running cronjob, you have to set up a temporary file yourself.

My suggestion at this point is to e.g. add `tee $HOME/cronjob.out` to your cronjob, which captures a copy of your job’s output in a safe place.

Answer (score -1):

You have to intercept the output (or find out where the temporary file is). Dunno how to do this in *BSD, sorry. But consider that unless that file is unbuffered, you'll get to see output only each time it fills up a buffer (prbably around 4 KiB), which could take quite some time.
Is it too costly just to do the comand by hand if you want to take a look of current status?